# how to install older version(2.6.9) of python on windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to install python version 2.6.9 on my windows 10 system , though there are windows installer available for other versions , but i did not find any downloadable windows installer for this version .

If you check the url : https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.9/ , you can download a tar.gz file for version 2.6.9 ,containing a folder for 2.6.9 , but I am still unsure how to install this on my windows machine

I searched web but I did not find any page telling how to install this on my windows system .

Generally you give path till bin in env variables , but when i extract the folder i did not find any bin folder , so i am not sure which folder to point .

I have also checked readme files , but there no info on the same inside those as well

There is something called pyenv to switch between different versions of python but it does not work on windows.

I also tried anaconda and miniconda , but after installation they say go to anaconda folder to run conda commands , which does not exist .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have seen on this page, this is a source only release, meaning that no binary artifact was produced. You would have to compile it yourself. For the 2.6 version, the last binary release was 2.6.6, which had (and still have) Windows binaries and installer, available here : https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/

Comment: genrally we are working on 2.6.9 , but since we do not have binary version for 2.6.9 ,so i am using 2.7 , i hope it will not cause any problem

Comment: You should probably be using 2.6.6, as it should not cause any problems, while 2.7 could quite easily. patches 2.6.7 to 2.6.9 were only security fix for a production context and should not be a major concern for a development setup, while 2.7 added a lot of features along with some syntax changes that could easily break things in your existing code.